# Fundamental change in how to specify culture in a Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8

From OnLaunched in App.cs

this is working...

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "da-DK";
```

but neither of these are...

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK");
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK");
```

I haven't reflectored it but shouldn't the latter be just as good ?

I am missing a point here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two is that `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK");`
is meant for defining the default culture of **newly created threads**. This means threads that are already running are not affected by it. To change the culture of a already runnning thread, you need to use the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property inside that running thread.

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "da-DK";
```

has a wider scope and will also modify the already running threads. But it's meant to be used more as a "language selection" within the application and not as a replacement for CultureInfo (which is not only used for language, but also for conversion, metrics, formatting etc.)

Comment: But changing the Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride does not change the app culture instantly, the app/frame needs to be restarted/navigated so that changes take place