# How to convert a decimal to any currency in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How can I convert a decimal value to any currency in WinRT? Actually I am doing the following:

```
decimal d=2;
d.toSring("C");
```

That gives me 2,00 € because I’m from the EU. How can I get this value in dollar? I know in ASP it works something like this:

```
decimal d=2;
d.toString("C",CultureInfo.getCulture("en-US"));
```

However the function **getCulture** is not available in WinRT.

Comment: Did you try `d.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));`

Comment: Thx Jingsore. That is the right answer. Don't know why I missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106919/fundamental-change-in-how-to-specify-culture-in-a-windows-8-app) for more details.

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
```