# How can I force the user language in a WinRT application?

Tags: localization, windows-runtime

I have a WinRT application with multiple languages.
The app use automatically the user language, but I want to let the user choose one of them manualy in my app.
Is it possible to do it in runtime ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106919/fundamental-change-in-how-to-specify-culture-in-a-windows-8-app